# Integrating twitter login in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter

In my IOS app i Want to add twitter login in order  to fetch the user's information like Name, Email ID and Profile picture.Can anyone please provide me some useful information or some tutorial link that can help in integrating twitter login in my app and to fetch user information.

Comment: Look up the twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to do some really simple login stuff and are new to iOS, I would definitely check out Parse's Twitter Login tools.

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#twitterusers/iOS

Really user friendly and simple to get the hang of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add twitter login to your app in a simple way, I would recommend you to use Fabric framework. Follow this link: https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/ios

Note: You can't bring user's email easily. You need to get permissions from twitter by filling a form in twitter website or else by sending email to fabric team.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Kit](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/overview) provides all the required functionalities and mechanism for making authenticated requests to Twitter's REST API.

Follow the configuration process [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/configure).

Using TWTRSession, you can request for TWTRUser object and that will have what you need.

This is the right way and advisable one too.

Comment: TwitterKit is part of Fabric. It can be downloaded from https://dev.twitter.com Follow the link that says "Download".

Comment: And follow the configuration process